# $f:X\rightarrow X$ be a continuous map, we need to show $f(\cap A_n)=\cap f(A_n)$

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

let $X$ be a complete metric space with metric $d$ and $A_{i}$'s are nested sequence of closed sets in $X$ i.e $[A_1\supseteq A_2\dots]$ such that $\sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in A_n\}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$

$f:X\rightarrow X$  be  a continuous map, we need to show $$f(\cap A_n)=\cap f(A_n)$$
My attempt:
Let $x\in f(\cap A_n)$ then there exists $y_n\in \cap A_n$ such that $f(y_n)=x$, The sequence $\{y_n\}$ converges to $y\in\cap A_n$ and also $\cap A_n=\{y\}$ by cantors intersection Theorem. so $f(y)=x$

Comment: $f(\cap_n A_n) \subseteq \cap_n f(A_n)$ does always hold, for trivial reasons. You have to show the other inclusion (using the assumptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y\in f(\cap A_n)$, then there exist $x\in\cap A_n$, such that $f(x)=y$. But $x\in \cap A_n$ implies that $x\in A_n$ for all $n$, hence, $y\in \cap f(A_n)$.

Now, suppose that $y\in \cap f(A_n)$. This implies that for all $n$, there exist $a_n\in A_n$ such that $f(a_n)=y$ By Hypothesis, $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence that 's converge for some $a\in \cap A_n$. Because $f$ is continuous you can conclude.